# puppet not upgrading in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: puppet

I installed puppet in Ubuntu 12.04 from apt respository. Current version is 2.7.11
I am trying to upgrade to puppet 3 by following

```
wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

But this is what the result

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
puppet is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
```

It's always staying at 2.7.11.... :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to purge Puppet first so it knows that you want to install latest version available.

`apt-get purge puppet`

Comment: Are you sure about that ??

Comment: @Arun No, he is not.

Comment: Matt, Its upgraded to puppet 3.0.1 both places ( apt and in gem )... I did upgraded to 3.0.1 using gem, But I am not quite sure how its upgraded to 3.0.1 in system....I am still wondering.... Do you have any clue about this?