# Upgrade puppet on Ubuntu to puppet 5

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I'm very new to puppet and VMs so I'm struggling to understand the documentation and everything.

I've been given a repo which needs to run on puppet 5, so I set myself out to running it and see what it does.

I started by grabbing a linux VM (Ubuntu 16.04) and doing puppet --version on the terminal which gives me version 3.8.5, thus I need to upgrade this.

Question now is how do I upgrade it? The documentation from PuppetLabs go into detail about upgrading puppet-agents and masters and servers and I'm lost in it all... I think what I want is a standalone self-contained architecture? The agent/master architecture seems like even more work and unnecessary for my case. PuppetLabs documentation (https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/install_pre.html) focuses more on agent/server setup with pretty much nothing on the standalone architecture. I've tried the steps for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/puppet_platform.html#ubuntu-1604-xenial-xerus to no avail, the version remains at 3.8.5 even when installing puppet5.

I tried this [puppet not upgrading in Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347305/puppet-not-upgrading-in-ubuntu-12-04)
which got me to version 3.8.5, but how do I get to v5?

For a little more context, here's a simple test I want to do, call test::passVar and print to the terminal the value being passed:

```
init.pp

class test() {
    notice("test")
    test::passVar { "Test passing a variable":
      test_var => 'testVar',
    }
}


passVar.pp

define test::passVar (
    $test_var,
) {
    notice("test notice")
    notice($test_var)
}
```

To run this, I've done

```
puppet apply init.pp
```

The output says it's compiled and finished but I don't see anything printed out from the notice() calls.

So perhaps I need v5 to run this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the docs over at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/install_linux.html you'll see a section (after setting up the appropriate repositories, which you did above)

> 3.Install the puppet-agent package on your Puppet agent nodes using the command appropriate to your system:
>
> ◦Yum – sudo yum install puppet-agent
>
> ◦Apt – sudo apt-get install puppet-agent
>
> ◦Zypper – sudo zypper install puppet-agent

It appears that you did `sudo apt-get install puppet`, which still points to the system package in the base Ubuntu repositories, which is version 3.8.5

The other thing to mention is that puppet is not in your path by default, it is installed under /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet, as referenced in step 5 of the above mentioned setup doc  If you wish to call it from your terminal, you will need to make sure that location is in your path.

> 5.Start the puppet service: sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet resource service puppet ensure=running enable=true.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are installing the default package that comes within the default repositories, so to get puppet 5 into your system you have to instal the puppetlabs repository.

```
wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-xenial.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-pc1-xenial.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

The code that you are testing is very generic so that will run almost into any puppet version, try adding —debug flag to your command and see if the notice function shows out something.

Comment: The only difference between your steps compared with https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/puppet_platform.html#ubuntu-1604-xenial-xerus is that yours has "pc1". Either way, I've tried both and nothing happens, puppet --version still spits out 3.8.5

Comment: Duplicate of my comment below, but for puppet3, the puppet client package in Ubuntu is named 'puppet', in puppet4+, it is named 'puppet-agent'... see https://github.com/petems/puppet-install-shell for a cross platform 'install script'

Answer (score 2):

Was struggling with this today. Found this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iim09ULXV60.

tl;dr you need to grab puppet5 tarball from https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/puppet/ and install it.

```
$> wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-xenial.deb
$> sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-pc1-xenial.deb
$> sudo apt-get update
$> sudo apt-get install puppet
... same as Marvin Velasquez wrote above ...
$> puppet -V # output is still 3.8.5, wtf?

$> wget https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-5.3.3.tar.gz
$> tar -xzvf puppet-5.3.3.tar.gz # note: may want to untar this into a more permanent place than your homedir as I did.
$> cd puppet-5.3.3
$> sudo ./install.rb
$> puppet -V # output is 5.3.3
```

Can't explain why puppetlabs isn't serving a more recent release as the default, or why this info wasn't readily available on puppetlabs' site. Makes me feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The problem is that the newer versions of puppet have the agent in a package named 'puppet-agent', whereas puppet3 has the puppet client named 'puppet'.  After installing the puppet PPA, you should see a puppet-agent package in your list.. That should be covered in the install docs over at puppet.com

Answer (score 0):

There were substantial changes between puppet 3.8 and 4; it would be worth you reading about them.

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/index.html#upgrading-from-puppet-3

The upgrade documentation for puppet 5 says this about the upgrade path from 3.8: "Upgrading from Puppet 3.8.x
You can use the major upgrade guide to upgrade from Puppet 3.8.x, but this upgrade path hasn’t yet been tested or verified."

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/index.html#upgrading-from-puppet-38x

So I would suggest upgrading from 3.8 to 4.10 first; and then to 5.x

Answer (score -2):

So the solution ended up not really being a solution... I tried my exact same steps on RHEL7 and that installed puppet 5 with no hassles so I'm using that instead. Still no idea with Ubuntu 16.04 but I'm not fussy of where I run it.

Comment: The problem is in puppet3, the package is named 'puppet', in puppet 4+, it is named 'puppet-agent', so even if you install the puppet 'ppa', if you give it the name 'puppet' it won't install what you are expecting